# Backbone.js validation error appears in more than one view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having trouble with a backbone.js app I'm working on as a learning exercise. I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidavilasilva/teCeL/) for it.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var app = {};
$(document).ready(function() {

  app.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: ''
    },
    validate: function(attrs) {
      var errors = [];
      if (attrs.firstName.trim() == "") {
        errors.push({
          'message': 'Please enter a first name.',
          'field': 'firstName'
        });
      }
      if (attrs.lastName.trim() == "") {
        errors.push({
          'message': 'Please enter a last name.',
          'field': 'lastName'
        });
      }
      if (attrs.email.trim() == "") {
        errors.push({
          'message': 'Please enter an email address.',
          'field': 'email'
        });
      }
      if (errors.length) {
        return errors;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  app.ContactList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Contact,
    localStorage: new Store('backbone-addressbook')
  });

  app.contactList = new app.ContactList();

  app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($('#contact-template').html()),
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
      this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
      var self = this;
      this.model.on('invalid', function(model, errors) {
        _.each(errors, function(error, i) {
          console.log(self.el);
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().find('.help-block').remove();
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().append('<span class="help-block">' + error.message + '</span>');
        });
      });
      this.model.on('change', function(model, response) {
        //console.log(self.el);
        $(self.el).removeClass('editing');
        this.render;
      })
    },
    events: {
      'dblclick label': 'edit',
      'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
      'click .destroy': 'destroy',
      'click .save': 'close'
    },
    edit: function(e) {
      this.$el.addClass('editing');
      $(e.currentTarget).next('input').focus();
    },
    updateOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        this.close(e);
      }
    },
    close: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var updateObject = {};
      $(this.el).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        node = $(this);
        updateObject[node.data('field')] = node.val();
      });
      this.model.save(updateObject, {validate: true});
    },
    destroy: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    }
  });

  app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#newContact',
    initialize: function() {
      $(this).find('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
      $(this).remove('.help-block');
      app.contactList.on('add', this.addOne, this);
      app.contactList.fetch();
      var self = this;
      app.contactList.on('invalid', function(model, errors) {
        _.each(errors, function(error, i) {
          console.log(self.el);
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().find('.help-block').remove();
          $(self.el).find('[data-field="' + error.field + '"]').parent().append('<span class="help-block">' + error.message + '</span>');
        });
      });
    },
    events: {
      'click .add': 'createContact'
    },
    createContact: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      app.contactList.create(this.newAttributes(), {validate: true});
    },
    addOne: function(contact) {
      var view = new app.ContactView({model: contact});
      $('#contactList').append(view.render().el);
      $('form input[type="text"]').val('');
      $('form input[type="text"]').parent().removeClass('has-error');
      $('.help-block').remove();
    },
    newAttributes: function() {
      var updateObject = {};
      $(this.el).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        node = $(this);
        updateObject[node.data('field')] = node.val();
      });
      return updateObject;
    },
  });

  app.appView = new app.AppView();

});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <section id="addressbookapp">
      <header id="header">
          <h1>Address Book</h1>
          <div class="well">
          <form id="newContact" action="#" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                  <input data-field="firstName" class="newFirstName form-control input-sm" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                  <input data-field="lastName" class="newLastName form-control input-sm" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
                  <input data-field="email" class="newEmail form-control input-sm" type="text" />
              </div>
              <button class="add btn-xs">Add</button>
          </form>
          </div>
      </header>
      <section id="main">
          <table class="table table-striped">
              <caption>Double-click to edit an entry.</caption>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>First</th>
                      <th>Last</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th></th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="contactList"></tbody>
          </table>
      </section>
  </section>
</div>
<script id="contact-template" type="text/template">
    <form action="#" role="form">
      <td>
        <label class="control-label" for="firstName"><%- firstName %></label>
        <input data-field="firstName" class="firstName input-sm edit" value="<%- firstName %>" type="text" />
      </td>
    <td>
      <label class="control-label" for="lastName"><%- lastName %></label>
      <input data-field="lastName" class="lastName input-sm edit" value="<%- lastName %>" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="control-label" for="email"><%- email %></label>
      <input data-field="email" class="email input-sm edit" value="<%- email %>" type="email" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn-xs save">Save</button>
      <button class="btn-xs destroy">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </form>
</script>
```

Specifically, when the user edits an entry in the list (by double-clicking), clears an input (a last name, for example) and then tries to save, there's (correctly) a validation error. The problem is that the form at the top (for creating a new entry) is also responding to the invalid event.

My question is not just how to keep this from happening but what would be the ideal way to organize things. This is a learning exercise for me, so I'd thankful for any tips -- anything you see that could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the way you've built the app: in both the "new" and "edit" forms, you tell the app to "display error messages if there's a validation problem in the collection". So when you try editing an existing model and there's a validation problem, the "new" form updates to display the errors.

What you need to do instead, is use a new (blank) model in the "new" form, display errors if it doesn't validate, and add it to the collection if it's valid. That way, both forms have their errors handled by different mechanisms and won't overlap.

See http://jsfiddle.net/n9yq2/3/

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#newContact',
    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new app.Contact();

    // edited for brevity

    this.model.on('invalid', function(model, errors) {
        _.each(errors, function(error, i) {



createContact: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        var attrs = this.newAttributes();
        if(this.model.set(attrs, {validate: true})){
          app.contactList.create(attrs);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Excellent. It works, and your explanation is clear. You really helped me to understand this better. Thanks very much.